# Groovy Sql Execute Statement won't accept closures

Tags: sql, groovy, groovy-sql

I have a statement:

```
sqlInstance.execute(executeString){
                    dummy, realList->
                    debug("Real LIst: "+realList)

                    }
```

which fails with 'Invalid column type'

But:

```
def bool = sqlInstance.execute(executeString)
```

works.  If I print bool, it prints as 'true'.

For reference:

```
executeString = "select distinct channel_id from guide_sched"
```

For some reason, the closure isn't working for the execute method in groovy's Sql, although I've checked the documentation and it's supposed to.

Comment: Can you also mention what is `sqlInstance` and how is it instantiated?

Comment: Also include your error message.  And what are the types of `dummy` and `realList`?  The docs [say](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#execute(java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) that the closure takes "two parameters: either true plus a list of GroovyRowResult values derived from statement.getResultSet() or false plus the update count from statement.getUpdateCount()". Your closure params don't sound like they match that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the first environment I was testing on ran Groovy 2.4 and the second runs Groovy 2.1.  The execute statement I was using didn't exist until after 2.1

Instead, I used the .rows() function to return a GroovyRowResult which I parsed for the information I needed, instead of accessing it directly in the .execute() closure.